Resolving External $ref Paths With Nested Refs in NSwag for OpenAPI Specification in C#
I am using NSwag in a .NET environment to generate a C# client from an OpenAPI 3.0.1 specification. My OpenAPI specification includes components that are defined in external files, but NSwag is failing to resolve these external references, specifically with nested schemas.
When attempting to generate the C# client, I encounter errors like System.InvalidOperationException: Could not resolve the path '#/components/schemas/SomeSchema'. This error suggests that NSwag cannot resolve the external references, even though the paths are correctly specified.
Here is what the ref looks like:
components:
  schemas:
    SomeSchema:
      $ref: './external_definitions.yml#/components/schemas/SomeSchema'


EDIT: Here is an example of the SomeSchema definition - the issue are the nested references I believe:
SomeSchema:
  type: object
  properties:
    Version:
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    Identifier:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/UniqueIdentifier'
      nullable: true
    Name:
      type: string
      nullable: true
    Organization:
      type: string
      nullable: true
    ModifiedTime:
      type: string
      format: date-time
      nullable: true
    ModifiedBy:
      type: string
      nullable: true
    Status:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/StatusType'
      nullable: true
    Details:
      type: string
      nullable: true
    Labels:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
      nullable: true
    Category:
      type: string
      nullable: true
    ReviewPeriod:
      type: string
      format: time-span
      nullable: true
    UpdateFrequency:
      type: string
      format: time-span
      nullable: true
    Calculations:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/CalculationType'
      nullable: true
    DataSources:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/DataSourceType'
      nullable: true
    Dimensions:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/DimensionFilterType'
      nullable: true
    Conditions:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/ConditionType'
      nullable: true
    Outputs:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/OutputType'
      nullable: true
    ExtendedConfig:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/AdvancedConfigType'
      nullable: true
    AutoAdjustmentConfig:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/AdjustmentConfigType'
      nullable: true
    EnrichmentConfig:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/EnrichmentConfigType'
      nullable: true
    Metadata:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        type: string
      nullable: true
    HandlingNullData:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullDataHandlingType'
      nullable: true
    DeploymentMetadata:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/DeploymentMetadataType'
      nullable: true

I've confirmed the file paths are correct relative to where NSwag is executed.
Tried simplifying the $ref to reference simpler schemas which worked, but nested ones fail.
The reason I am doing this is because, I want to have a spec for a gateway use schemas for a spec from another service, and to avoid duplicating these.
Another option which seemed to work was having the nested schemas also be referenced, but, there are too many and ultimately this becomes very messy to me.
Has anyone successfully resolved external $ref paths with nested schemas using NSwag?
Are there any specific configurations or workarounds in NSwag or NJsonSchema that I might be missing to handle this situation better?
Any help or pointers towards what might be going wrong or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT:
I tried to extract the shared components into its own OpenAPI spec, and then have the other specs consume it, the components spec was defined like so - please ignore any obvious syntax errors:
data.yml:
components:
  schemas:
    SomeSchema:
    type: object
    properties:
      Version:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
      Identifier:
        $ref: './data.yml#/components/schemas/UniqueIdentifier'
        nullable: true
      Name:
        type: string
        nullable: true
      Organization:
        type: string
        nullable: true
      ModifiedTime:
        type: string
        format: date-time
        nullable: true
      ModifiedBy:
        type: string
        nullable: true
      Status:
        $ref: './data.yml#/components/schemas/StatusType'
        nullable: true
      Details:
        type: string
        nullable: true
      Labels:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
        nullable: true
      Category:
        type: string
        nullable: true
      ReviewPeriod:
        type: string
        format: time-span
        nullable: true
      UpdateFrequency:
        type: string
        format: time-span
        nullable: true
      Calculations:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: './data.yml#/components/schemas/CalculationType'
        nullable: true
      DataSources:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: './data.yml#/components/schemas/DataSourceType'
        nullable: true
      Dimensions:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: './data.yml#/components/schemas/DimensionFilterType'
        nullable: true
      Conditions:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: './data.yml#/components/schemas/ConditionType'
        nullable: true
      Outputs:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: './data.yml#/components/schemas/OutputType'
        nullable: true
      ExtendedConfig:
        $ref: './data.yml#/components/schemas/AdvancedConfigType'
        nullable: true
      AutoAdjustmentConfig:
        $ref: './data.yml#/components/schemas/AdjustmentConfigType'
        nullable: true
      EnrichmentConfig:
        $ref: './data.yml#/components/schemas/EnrichmentConfigType'
        nullable: true
      Metadata:
        type: object
        additionalProperties:
          type: string
        nullable: true
      HandlingNullData:
        $ref: './data.yml#/components/schemas/NullDataHandlingType'
        nullable: true
      DeploymentMetadata:
        $ref: './data.yml#/components/schemas/DeploymentMetadataType'
        nullable: true

However, I am getting errors on the second last property when referencing SomeSchema from another spec file in the same directory using the same ref -- so it seems to be working for most schemas but not all?
EDIT 12/05/2024: The issue still seems to be when there is deeper nesting, I validated this by removing the HandlingNullData property, and there were still failures.
EDIT 13/05/2024:
I am starting to believe these issues with external references may be an issue with the NSwag library itself:
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2871
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/pull/1098
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/4653
From NJsonSchema, which NSwag uses:
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/issues/1698
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/issues/1654
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/issues/1654
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/issues/566
Any help appreciated thank you

share a sample of the external-definitions.yaml file.

In the external file, does it have a top level components keyword?  You didn't show that but you have all your references pointing to it

@JeremyFiel yes it does have that sorry

The reference is valid, if I do CTRL + Left Click, it brings me to the correct schema in the external spec.
